# Why do I get network error when I try to use firebase to sign in with google using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to sign in with Google authentication using Firebase. I created a project on the Firebase console and I copied the configuration from there and pasted it in my project. I then selected sign in method and set Google to enabled (in the console) and it worked very well. However, after 2 days I ran my project again and I got this problem and I found I have network error

```
  121 | // Confirm iframe is correctly loaded.
  122 | // To fallback on failure, set a timeout.
  123 | var networkErrorTimer = setTimeout(function() {
> 124 |   reject(new Error('Network Error'));
  126 | // Clear timer and resolve pending iframe ready promise.
  127 | var clearTimerAndResolve = function() {
```

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FormInput from "../Form-input/FormInput";
import CustomerButton from "../Customer-Button/CustomerButton";
import { signInWithGoogle } from "../../FireBase/firebase.utils";
import "./SignIn.css";

class SignIn extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  handle = e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // preventing default
    this.setState({ email: "", password: "" });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sign-in" onSubmit={this.handle}>
      <h2>I already have an account</h2>
      <span>Sign In with your email and password</span>
      <form>
        <FormInput  // component 
          type="email"
          name="email"
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.email}
          required
          label="email"
        />
        <FormInput
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={this.state.email}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          required
          label="password"
        />
        <div className="button">
          <CustomButton type="submit">Sign In</CustomerButton> . // component 
          <CustomButton onClick={signInWithGoogle}> // here for sign in with google
            Sign In With GOOGLE
          </CustomerButton>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignIn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not sure but it could be à CORS issue, try to use a browser extension that enables CORS

Comment: oh, yeah I have tried that right no and it worked , thank you so much